# compilar mix laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Olá, estou com um problema no laravel 5.4 estou tentando colocar uma biblioteca js pessoal minha e nao estou conseguindo e nem remover o vue

meu package.json

```js
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4"
  }
}
```

Meu assests/js/app.js

```js
 require('./bootstrap');
```

e meu webpack.mix.js

```js
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');



 mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
 .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
 .js('resources/assets/js/cidades-estados-1-4.js', 'public/js');
```

dou um npm update depois um npm run dev ou prod mas ele nao atualiza, ainda esta com o vue.js que ja removi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta o seguinte:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .scripts([
      'resources/assets/js/cidades-estados-1-4.js'
    ], 
    'public/js/app.js'
);
```

Comment: Deu certo, vlw demais